# How to add external source link for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a exernal link for jquery source. But the jquery event doesn't get fired. Is the format that I specified the jquery source and the jquery method call are correct ?

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
    <style>/* root element for accordion. decorated with rounded borders and gradient background image */
.accordion {
    background:#333;
    width: 90%;
    border:1px solid #333;    
    -background:#666;
}

/* accordion header */
.accordion h2 {
    background:#ccc url('http://static.flowplayer.org/img/global/gradient/h30.png');
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 15px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #000;
}

/* currently active header */
.accordion h2.current {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#0f0;
}

/* accordion pane */
.accordion .pane {
    display:none;

    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* a title inside pane */
.accordion .pane h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 -5px 0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#999;
}</style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Initialising Accordion
            $(".accordion").tabs(".pane", {
                tabs: '> h2',
                effect: 'slide',
                initialIndex: null
            });

            //The click to hide function
            $(".accordion > h2").click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
                    $(this).next().slideUp();
                    $(this).removeClass("current");
                } else if (!$(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
                    $(this).next().slideDown();
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
    <h2>Level 1:1</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        <div class="accordion">
            <h2>Level 2 : 1</h2>
            <div class="pane">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <h2>Set 1</h2>
                    <div class="pane">
                        <div class="accordion">
                            <h2>Test3</h2>
                            <div class="pane">
                                [Pane Content]
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Level 2 : 1</h2>
            <div class="pane">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <h2>Set 1</h2>
                    <div class="pane">
                        <div class="accordion">
                            <h2>Test3</h2>
                            <div class="pane">
                                [Pane Content]
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Level 1:2</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since it not accept my question saying it's smaller than the code, I just entered it twice. Sorry

Comment: include JqueryUI since tabs is part of jquery UI

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing in the console.

Comment: are you trying to make a nested accordion??

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaram can you try http://jsfiddle.net/xanetia/8kz4m/ ?

Comment: I don't see any error. Yes. I'm trying to do a nested accordion.

Comment: something similar to the left column section in jsfiddle website where it shows, Framework & Extensions, Fiddler Options, External Resources, Languages, Ajax Requests. It expands the contents based on the label that we click.

Comment: @Sushil In jsfiddle website it works. but not in my local

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaram have you included the JQuery UI js?

Comment: No. I tried now adding this
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
But did not work

Comment: what error are you getting in your console?